# Remove duplicates in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Here's what i have tried,

```
Criteria crv = ses.createCriteria(DB.Values.class);
crv.add(Restrictions.eq("categories", c));
crv.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
List<DB.Values> liv = crv.list();
```

it still gives duplicate values

this doesn't work either,

```
Criteria crv = ses.createCriteria(DB.Values.class);
crv.add(Restrictions.eq("categories", c));
crv.setProjection(Projections.property("description"));
List<DB.Values> liv = crv.list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Criteria cr = ses.createCriteria(DB.Categories.class);
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq("description", cat));
            DB.Categories c = (DB.Categories) cr.uniqueResult();

            Criteria crv = (Criteria) ses.createCriteria(DB.Values.class)
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("description")))
                    );
            crv.add(Restrictions.eq("categories", c));
                   List<String> liv = crv.list();
```

This code answers my question